Integration formula on locally compact groups
Let $G$ be a unimodular locally compact group with Haar measure $\mu_G$ and $H\leq G$ a (not necessarily unimodular) closed subgroup with left Haar measure $\mu_H.$ Let $\Delta_H$ be the modular function of $H.$ Following Proposition 8.1.3 and Theorem 8.1.13 in "Classical Harmonic Analysis and Locally Compact Groups" by Reiter and Stegeman, there exists a strictly positive continuous function $\lambda_H : G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ satisfying the functional equation $\lambda_H(gh) = \lambda_H(g) \Delta_H(h)$ for all $g \in G, h \in H$ and a quasi-invariant measure $\mu_{G/H}$ on $G/H$ satisfying
$$
\int_{G} f(g) \lambda_H(g) \, d \mu_{G}(g) = \int_{G / H} \int_{H} f(g h )  \, d \mu_{H}(h) d \mu_{G/H}(g H).
$$
I am interested in a slightly more general case, where one considers an additional closed unimodular subgroup $\Gamma \leq H \leq G$ and would like to express the integral over $G/\Gamma$ as integrals over $G/H$ and $H/\Gamma$. Does a similar formula hold? I would appreciate any references or clarifications. Thank you.

I do not have easy access to your cited source, so I don't know what approach they took... Nevertheless:
One way to approach this is to think of the Riesz-Markov-Kakutani theorem, that a "suitable" (e.g., positive...) functional on compactly-supported continuous functions is equal to integration with respect to a Borel measure ("regular", when the space on which the functions live is locally compact, Hausdorff, and maybe has a countable basis...) Then, because we can prove in a relatively elementary fashion that the obvious averaging maps $f\to (g\to \int_H f(gx)\,dx) $ are surjective, we obtain the desired equality.
(For uniqueness, generalizing uniqueness of Haar measures (of course up to scalar multiples), there is a very-general uniqueness argument for $G$-invariant functionals on various function spaces on $G$...)

Thank you for the answer, it was helpful.
